# Calling a method of a controller in Altorouter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, router, altorouter

I have been trying to get the index() method of the Home controller using the altorouter but am unable to. I have searched a few places but I could not find any help.

Here is the index.php

```
<?php

include 'system/startup.php';
include 'library/AltoRouter.php';

// Router
$router = new AltoRouter();
// Change here before upload
$router->setBasePath('/demo');
$router->map('GET|POST','/', 'home#index', 'home');

// match current request
$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
} else {
    // no route matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

the home controller in the catalog>controller directory.

```
<?php
class home {
    public function index() {
        echo 'home';
    }
}
```

Can anyone using or who ever used this altorouter guide?.

P.S. I have the autoload function in the startup.php file (included at the top of the index.php)

Comment: What does your request look like?

Comment: @hd, this is supposed to be home .... on my xampp it's "localhost/demo"

Answer (score 0):

This is old thread but this can help you. You need match request in different way:

```
<?php

include 'system/startup.php';
include 'library/AltoRouter.php';

// Router
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->setBasePath('/demo');
$router->map('GET|POST','/', 'home#index', 'home');
$match = $router->match();

if ($match === false) {
    // here you can handle 404
} else {
    list( $controller, $action ) = explode( '#', $match['target'] );
    if ( is_callable(array($controller, $action)) ) {
        call_user_func_array(array($controller,$action), array($match['params']));
    } else {
        // here your routes are wrong.
        // Throw an exception in debug, send a  500 error in production
    }
}
```